# Spring XD facebook data extraction

Tags: spring-xd

Is there anyway to extract Facebook data using Spring XD?

I am now able to extract Facebook data using Graph api, Json, Java Program, but the question is if could I integrate this this to be executed automatically through Spring XD.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a custom source module](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#creating-a-source-module).

If it is general enough, consider contributing it to [spring-xd-modules](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules). The README has information about contributing.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the reply,
Yes, sure, I know that I can build a custom module, Can you please provide instructions, doc for that, I get lost with the Spring XD Guide.

thanks,
Moha.

Comment: You can take a look at some custom modules in [spring-xd-modules](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules); and there's a sample using the Spring Integration DSL in [spring-xd-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples).